# How can I force Drush to use PHP7

Tags: 8, drush

I have PHP5.6 and PHP7.2 installed. "php" runs 5.6 and "php72" runs 7.2.

For Drupal8, I want to run 7.2, which is fine when it's called from the webserver, but when I run drush it uses 5.6. I've tried to explicitly call with php72, but it returns errors such as:

```
php72 /usr/local/bin/drush status
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Table.php:789                                [warning]
 Drupal version                  :  8.8.0                                                                                          
 Site URI                        :  http://example.com                                                                           
 Database driver                 :  mysql                                                                                          
 Database hostname               :  localhost                                                                                      
 Database port                   :  3306                                                                                           
 Database username               :  example                                                                                     
 Database name                   :  example_drupal8                                                                             
 Drupal bootstrap                :  Successful                                                                                     
 Drupal user                     :                                                                                                 
 Default theme                   :  example_theme                                                                               
 Administration theme            :  seven                                                                                          
 PHP configuration               :  /etc/opt/remi/php72/php.ini                                                                    
 PHP OS                          :  Linux                                                                                          
 Drush script                    :  /usr/local/bin/drush                                                                           
 Drush version                   :  8.0.1                                                                                          
 Drush temp directory            :  /tmp                                                                                           
 Drush configuration             :                                                                                                 
 Drush alias files               :                                                                                                 
 Install profile                 :  standard                                                                                       
 Drupal root                     :  /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0                                                                   
 Site path                       :  sites/example.com                                                                            
 File directory path             :  sites/example.com/files                                                                      
 Private file directory path     :  /var/www/vhosts/brickfeile.ie/example_privatefiles                                          
 Temporary file directory path   :  /tmp                                                                                           
 Sync config path                :  sites/example.com/files/config_UJCyktKfDo6zGRcBaZlz8kmmKTyVx_y340I5KmjvtweOhyYvox5Rml_QYuTgx 
                                    DADGBRJzJlfcA/sync
```

Another example:

```
php72 /usr/local/bin/drush updb
The following updates are pending:

system module : 
  8801 -   Remove 'path.temporary' config if redundant. 
  8802 -   Fix system.theme:admin when the default theme is used as the admin theme. 
  8803 -   Install the 'path_alias' entity type. 
  8804 -   Convert path aliases to entities. 
  8805 -   Change the provider of the 'path_alias' entity type and its base fields. 

webform module : 
  8177 -   Issue #3082822: Anonymous role view submission via secure token. 

path module : 
  Create the language content settings configuration object for path aliases.

search module : 
  Configures default search page for instantiated blocks.

system module : 
  Populate the new 'match_limit' setting for the ER autocomplete widget.
  Clear the schema cache.

taxonomy module : 
  Add status with settings to all form displays for taxonomy entities.

text module : 
  Update text_with_summary fields and widgets to add summary required flags.

views module : 
  Define default values for limit operators settings in all filters.
  Remove core key from views configuration.

Do you wish to run all pending updates? (y/n): y
PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php on line 2
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php on line 50
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                      [error]
Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
/var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php, line 50
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.                                                 [error]
PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php on line 2
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php on line 50
Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                      [error]
Error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in
/var/www/drupal/drupal-8.8.0/vendor/typo3/phar-stream-wrapper/src/Behavior.php, line 50
The external command could not be executed due to an application error.                                                 [error]
Finished performing updates.                                                                                            [ok]
```

Any way I can run Drush with PHP 7 when PHP 5 is the default?

Comment: `I have PHP5.6` Why would you have an [unsupported version](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php) / dead, PHP5.6, installed in the first place?

Comment: No Sssweat its possible this person is using CentOS or RHEL or some distro that ships with that version as the default. It is also possible they have installed different versions of PHP for a need to support legacy projects that are incompatible with 7.x. In either case, the question Jaypan linked to should get you on the right track. James it looks like you are running Drush 8.0.1 too, have you tried also using Drush 9.7.0? Please see the Drush/Drupal/PHP version matrix here: https://docs.drush.org/en/master/install. 8.0.1 is not supported for Drupal 8.8.0.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. @No Sssweat: Yes, I have some legacy sites that still need PHP<7. I'll get around to converting them tMLo flat HTML at some point.

Comment: @Jaypan: That's really helpful. I now am sure I have Drush running with PHP7. Unfortunately I'm still getting some of the same errors, and it seems they are caused by some Pear libraries using PHP features that 7.2 no longer supports. I'm working on updating the Pear version.